# iPhone/iPad can't redirect to uncertified site

Tags: iphone, forms, ipad, ssl, certificate

So in our webapp, we have one project that is more of an hr tool and launches to specific portals for specific groups of people.  Each portal has it's own domain name.  When submitting the login redirect form to the portal on an ipad or iphone a blank screen is shown.  The redirect is just a form that gets submitted through a post to the portal.  Then on the portal, the form parameters are used to login the user.

I've confirmed that the blank screen is because our QA environment does not have the proper ssl certificates by first going to the portal and clicking proceed on the ssl certificate warning and then going back and launching the portal through the hr app.  In this scenario the portal gets loaded.  Is there any kind of workaround for this type of situation?  Why doesn't the iphone ask me if I want to proceed if I don't load the domain first?

I haven't seen anyone else ask this question and am having a hard time coming up with a solution.